# "ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[])' has some invalid arguments" in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, wcf

In the code below I have a *wcf* method and void method. When I execute it, it throws error

> "Error    170 The best overloaded method match for
>   'WebApp.MasterBiz.MastersClient.UpdateOtherExpenseCost(WebApp.MasterBiz.ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[])'
>   has some invalid arguments"

Please help me to solve the issue.

Void Method:

```
Dictionary<string, string> GRNCostInVals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
GRNCostInVals.Add("GRNID", hidGoodsReceivedNoteID.Value.ToString());
GRNCostInVals.Add("LoadingCost", txtLoadingCost.Value.ToString());
GRNCostInVals.Add("UnloadingCost", txtUnloadingCost.Value.ToString());
GRNCostInVals.Add("InsuranseCost", txtInsuranseCost.Value.ToString());
GRNCostInVals.Add("MiscCost", txtMiscCost.Value.ToString());
GRNCostInVals.Add("MiscDescription", txtMiscDesc.Value.ToString());
GRNCostInVals.Add("TransporterBillNo", txtTransporterBillNo.Value.ToString());
GRNCostInVals.Add("TransporterBillDate", txtTransporterBillDate.Value.ToString());
GRNCostInVals.Add("FreightCharges", txtTranspotationCost.Value.ToString());

objCost.UpdateOtherExpenseCost(GRNCostInVals);
```

WCF Method:

```
public int UpdateOtherExpenseCost(Dictionary<string, string> objCost)
{
    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] SqlParam = new SqlParameter[9];

        SqlParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@i_GRNID", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParam[0].Value = objCost["GRNID"];               

        SqlParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@nu_LoadingCost", SqlDbType.Float);
        SqlParam[1].Value = float.Parse(objCost["LoadingCost"]);

        SqlParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@nu_UnloadingCost", SqlDbType.Float);
        SqlParam[2].Value = float.Parse(objCost["UnloadingCost"]);

        SqlParam[3] = new SqlParameter("@nu_MiscCost", SqlDbType.Float);
        SqlParam[3].Value = float.Parse(objCost["MiscCost"]);

        SqlParam[4] = new SqlParameter("@vc_MiscDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        SqlParam[4].Value = objCost["MiscDescription"];

        SqlParam[5] = new SqlParameter("@nu_InsuranseCost", SqlDbType.Float);
        SqlParam[5].Value = float.Parse(objCost["InsuranseCost"]);

        SqlParam[6] = new SqlParameter("@vc_TransporterBillNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlParam[6].Value = objCost["TransporterBillNo"];

        SqlParam[7] = new SqlParameter("@dt_TransporterBillDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        SqlParam[7].Value = DateTime.Parse(objCost["TransporterBillDate"]);

        SqlParam[8] = new SqlParameter("@nu_TransportationCost", SqlDbType.Float);
        SqlParam[8].Value = float.Parse(objCost["FreightCharges"]);

        SqlHelper SqlHelp = new SqlHelper();
        return SqlHelp.ExecuteNonQuery(SqlParam, "Sp_UpdateOtherExpenseCost");


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        GmasSupportException GmasSupportEx = new GmasSupportException();
        GmasSupportEx.ExceptionType = ex.GetType().ToString();
        GmasSupportEx.Message = ex.Message.ToString();
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
            GmasSupportEx.InnerExceptionMessage = ex.InnerException.Message;

        throw new FaultException<GmasSupportException>(GmasSupportEx, new FaultReason(ex.Message.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code when you post. The more readable your question is, the more likely you are to get a response. Additionally, as the problem is simply *calling* the method (at compile-time), the details of the implementation are irrelevant - as are the values you're putting into the dictionary, although at least that's briefer...

Comment: @Jon Skeet How can i solve the issue?

Comment: I don't know enough about WCF to know what to expect, but I've given you suggestions to improve your question, so that people who *do* know WCF are more likely to help you. (It looks like the WCF proxy code is generating a `ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring` class for you - perhaps you could convert your dictionary into that?)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that when you imported the *Service Reference* something went wrong when mapping your **Dictionary**.

Or maybe you had added it as *Web Reference* instead of the new *Service Reference*.

You can try add the reference again and verify that the `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` **is** the  `Dictionary` collection type used and the Collection type **is** `System.Collection.Generic.List`.

Other than that you can provide the exact object the proxy is waiting so your code will look like this:

```
using WebApp.MasterBiz;
//...
var GRNCostInVals = new ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring[2];

GRNCostInVals[0] = new ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring();
GRNCostInVals[0].Key = "GRNID";
GRNCostInVals[0].Value = hidGoodsReceivedNoteID.Value.ToString();

GRNCostInVals[1] = new ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring();
GRNCostInVals[1].Key = "LoadingCost"
GRNCostInVals[1] = txtLoadingCost.Value.ToString();
//...
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with that? And I think you can remove the code inside your method `UpdateOtherExpenseCost`. It adds nothing to the problem.